# Invalid Syntax on MUD Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

pretty much spent a whole term getting this python code typed up and ready to go although I'm hitting some speedbumps and it is causing me to panic as the assignment is due tomorrow. I'm not too sure how to fix it so if anyone can please fix this, I would be so happy!

I'm quite new to this website so here is my full code for Python 3.5.1

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zoupk8z1sdqncpb/MUD%20File%20%281%29.py?dl=0

I am pretty much-begging someone to please send me back a fixed version of whatever is preventing this code from working.

Thanks
- Tyson

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You shouldn't be swearing in your question.

Comment: Rather than posting a link to your code and no real information, your question would be much better received if you included the actual error message and the relevant portion of the code.

Comment: Skimming your code, I noticed your mixing up your global variables and local variables in some of your functions. Might want to fix that up first. 

Second, what is the problem? What is happening that you didn't want? What is the desired output? 

Throwing your code here and expecting us to fix it with out telling us what's wrong, isn't helpful. We aren't mind readers. Edit your question and maybe we can help.

Comment: Apologies, im just very stressed with this assignment and for it to not work now is a nightmare in itself.

Answer (score -1):

Your Error is invalid Syntax, which comes from not correctly opening and closing.
Looking trough the code I see huge varation in formating style starting at `rooms = {`compared to the rest of the code.

I've put some quotes inbetween the part I suspect to be wrong and it runs directly. line 161 - 214:

```
"""
rooms = {

            1 : {  "name"  : "Engine 1" ,
                   "south" : 2,
                } ,        

            2 : {  "name"  : "Airlock" ,
                   "north" : 1 ,
                   "south" : 3,
                   "east"  : 4,
                   "item" : "Plasma"
                } ,

            3 : { "name" : "Engine 2" ,
                  "north" : 2 ,
                  "item" : "Pistol"
                } ,

            4 :{  "name" : "Hallway" ,
                  "east" : 5 ,
                  "west" : 2 ,
                  "monster" : "Manite Protecter"
               },

            5 :{  "name" : "Data Center" ,
                  "north" : 6 ,
                  "east" : 8 ,
                  "south" : 7 ,
                  "west" : 4 ,
                  "monster" : "Tero-L21"
               },

            6 :{  "name" : "Weapon Command Centre" ,
                  "south" : 5 ,
                  "item" : "Plasma_X31_AR" ,
                  "monster" : "Possessed Security Officer" ,
               },
            7 :{  "name" : "Quarantine" ,
                  "north" : 8 ,
                  "monster" : "Xenon Sentry" ,
               } ,
            8 :{  "name" : "Cockpit" ,
                  "monster" : "Xenon Overwatch" ,
         } ,


{
#start the player in room 1    
currentRoom == 1:        
showMap()
showInstructions()
}
"""
```

Comment: You shouldn't be answering code dump questions in the first place, but if you're going to do it, at least actually answer the question. The asker knows it's a problem with invalid syntax, and I'm sure the error message gives a general idea of where, if not the exact line number. Explain what is wrong with it and how to fix it. Just saying "I commented out this chunk of code and the error goes away" isn't an answer.

Comment: You both actually provide nothing to the OP. I told him where the error is in his 270 lines of code with no other information at hand than "it does not work" he doesnt open and close the paranthesis properly its the whole section i've commented out. If you don't at least take the time to look at someone's problem than you shouldn't critique someone who actually DOES!  Now go troll someone else.

Comment: You barely provide anything. The error message (yes, I did actually run it) points out an exact line to start looking. You pointed out a 50 line block of code and said commenting all this out makes the error go away, when you could have helped to actually fix it by specifically pointing out that `rooms` should have been closed right before the line `#start the player in room 1` by changing the `{` to `}` and that the final `}` needs to be removed. Then you didn't even address the line `currentRoom == 1:` which, depending on the intention there, has multiple fixes required.

Comment: You didnt provide anything up til now. the whole 50 line block is erroneous it is not advised in stackoverflows guidelines on how to write an answer, to do the work for the OP in reformating his code. I did however explain where the error is coming from and how to fix it. If you think you do better, you're welcome to fix his formatting, unless you do so you have no right in complaigning about the work someone else did to help!

Comment: What work did you do to help? You literally only pointed out what the error message already says, which OP has read or else he wouldn't have mentioned invalid syntax in the question. I didn't provide anything because questions along the lines of "here's a link to my code, someone fix it" are off-topic for StackOverflow. If you're so insistent on posting an answer, _put some effort into it_ and I _might_ consider removing my downvote. But as it is, this really does not answer the question. At best it should have been a comment.

Comment: The work you see right here in my answer. Yeah and I literally pointed out more than you. He did not mention the error type in his question that's what you assume. You don't understand, I don't care about your downvote. I come to Stack to help people not to collect points. If you're so eager to point out bad effort in answers, make your own answer and be better. Critizicing someone who actually provides help (his code is running with my "fix"), is helping no one.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Define running. Even after fixing the code you pointed out (actually fixing it, not just commenting it out), there are still dozens of other errors (they might have been added since yesterday, that's the problem with links). I appreciate that you want to help, but you don't seem to get that commenting out a section of code doesn't fix anything and doesn't answer anything. Yes, that particular syntax error is no longer a problem, but it doesn't address the actual issue. All I'm trying to advise you to do is to _actually fix_ that code and maybe even explain what was wrong with it.

Comment: Same as you however, I am not going to do that, I've spent time to run his code, without any informaiton of what actually is not working. If the OP wants me to rewrite his code he should put in some effort as well by adding which section of his code he tries to debug. I'm split between his post being lazy and being desperate which is why I even answered here. I however encourage you to do it better than I did.

Comment: The title says "invalid syntax", so yes I am assuming that he wants help fixing the existing syntax errors. That's a couple quick fixes. Any problems with the behavior itself are indeed missing from the question and are up to him to fix. You and I seem to be in agreement that there are issues with the question being asked in the first place, and those issues are why I'm not going to post an answer. But again, all I'm saying is it would be better if you actually showed how to fix it. It's up to you if you want to or not. I won't be returning to this page. Have a good day